# replace (') with ('') within string but not the start and end ones

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string in which I want to convert **single quote** to **two single quotes**. But do not convert the single quote at the start and end of the string.

For input and output:

**input** -> `test is 'Are you there'`
**output** -> `test is 'Are you there'`

**input** -> `test is 'Are y'ou there'`
**output** -> `test is 'Are y''ou there'`

I use the below code:

```
re.compile(r"(?<!\()'(?!\))").sub(string="test is 'Are you there'", repl="''")
```

But it results in `test is ''Are you there''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Lookbehind & Lookahead`

**Ex:**

```
import re

d = ["test is 'Are you there'", "test is 'Are y'ou there'"]
for i in d:
    print(re.sub(r"(?<=[A-Za-z])'(?=[A-Za-z])", "''", i))
```

**Output:**

```
test is 'Are you there'
test is 'Are y''ou there'
```